# How can the Azure Active Directory Authentication Service be forced to reissue an id_token with updated claims?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C to authenticate our users which is working fine.  After signup we add some custom claims to our users which were defined in the B2C portal as "User attributes" using the graph api.  When I log into the portal I can see these values have been set by our calls, as have some standard claims values(i.e. we also set Display Name by concatenating the givenName and lastName values).

The issue we are having is that after these values are set, they do not appear in the token retrieved by sending the access token to the authenticate endpoints until the user is logged out and back in again (which is obviously a pretty awful user experience after signup).  It looks like the original id_token is cached when the user is created and that is what is being returned instead.

This doesnt make sense, as it seems perfectly sensible to let a user update their profile (claims values) while logged into an application and for those changes to take affect immediately without needing to re-authenticate?

Could someone explain how/if it is possible to force the cached id_token on the server to expire so that when we request a id_token using an access token, the id_token contains the most up-to-date claims values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so after nearly a month of waiting for a response, the official line is:

"Product Group identify that this is on the roadmap even that we still don't have a final date it should happen in a few months."

So basically they haven't acknowledged it's a bug and they can't tell when this scenario will be supported.  Pretty poor level of support to be honest.

Comment: Further thoughts on what i'm trying to do and the frustrations around it:

http://www.rndthoughts.co.uk/2017/02/10/azure-active-directory-claims-extensions-issues-and-identical-emails/

Answer (score 4):

> The issue we are having is that after these values are set, they do not appear in the token retrieved by sending the access token to the authenticate endpoints until the user is logged out and back in again (which is obviously a pretty awful user experience after signup).

Would you mind show the request detail about how you acquire the id_token?

Based on my test, I can acquire the id_token with updated claim successful like steps below:

1 . sign-in a web app

2 . update the **DisplayName** using Azure AD Graph like below:

```
POST: https://graph.windows.net/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/users/{userId}?api-version=1.6
{
     "displayName":"newValue"
}
```

3. re-request the id_token from OAuth2.0 Authorization endpoint using HTTP request without sign-out/sign-in( You also can capture the exact request using Fiddler when you sign-in the app)

```
 GET:https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectURL}&response_type=id_token&scope=email+openid&response_mode=query&nonce=HWUavSky1PksCJC5Q0xHsw%3d%3d&nux=1&nca=1&domain_hint={XXXX.onmicrosoft.com}
```

4 . the update claim value show in the new id_token as expected

To narrow down this issue, you may see whether there is cache for the id_token in your app.

Comment: Can you explain a little better?  In point 3 you are making a call to the authorize endpoint but you don't specify how the server knows you have already authenticated and your identity at this point.  Is the browser re-sending the authentication token in the header as well?

Comment: The id_token is issued from the authorization endpoint instead of the token endpoint based on the [OpenId connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code/). And since the browser has the cookie for the Azure AD since I have sign-in the web app in step1, so I can get the id_token directly without authenticate again. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Fei, we are making these calls using a Xamarin Auth component so they are not made through the browser but directly using HttpWebRequest.  When we try making your suggested request in this manner, we get an error message back about the client not supporting javascript.  We have added the token data to the header when making this request but we get redirected to the login page.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Using .net, after login I can get the current user with ClaimsPrincipal.Current. I need to refresh the list of claims on this object without a relog.

Comment: Thanks for putting the bounty on Chris, I would have done the same but I dont have enough rep yet!  I also have a ticket open with the Azure support team around this issue but not getting much joy yet.  I will post if i get any answer but it feels like either a bug in the B2C implementation or a lack of documentation.

Comment: Hey guys,  quick clarification.  The difference between getting the token from the Authorization endpoint and the Token endpoint is whether you are using Implicit Flow, or Authorization Code flow.  Implicit flow (where you get it from the Authorization endpoint directly) is usually considered better for clients apps that are 100% in the hands of users (like javascript or mobile apps) because with Authorization Code flow you expose your client secret to anyone who decompiles or looks at source. Both flows are part of the OAuth2 and OpenId Connect Specs.

Comment: @RNDThoughts No problem. My workaround for this at the moment is to query the user's claims for our custom attribute and if it's missing fallback to querying the graph api for it. If both values are missing it's presumed to be not set. I'd really like to find a way to simply refresh the claims though as this feels like a hack.

Comment: Just an update - absolutely NO support from Microsoft around this issue at all.  Last contact I had was over a week ago and now utter silence, really unimpressed.  I have no idea how to reach out to them over this, it feels like I'm a small fish in a big pond.